# Word for being too fearful

Tags: single-word-requests

Word for being too fearful to act. Sort of like apprehensive but I need a stronger word. Any ideas?

Comment: What did a thesaurus tell you and why weren't those right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual *expression* is 'paralysed by fear'.

*Petrified* in the metaphorical sense is also common.

Though I'm not sure how many Belgian Shepherd Dogs use either.

Comment: I thought it was Berkeley Software Distribution ;)